# jQuery click function and slideToggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

My problem is that when a user clicks on the `<h4>` it opens the hidden `<div>` below it. That's great - works as expected. However when a user clicks back on the same `<h4>` - it closes the `<div>` and reopens it instantly.

I need the `<div>` to stay closed. I also need the remaining functionality to stay in place.

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#winners-table div').hide();
        $('div#winners-table h4').click(function(){
            $('div#winners-table h4.open').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('class', 'closed');
                $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
                });
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

**EDIT**
This is my HTML:

```
<div id="winners-table">
        <h3>...</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div>...</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div>...</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div>...</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div>...</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your desired behavior concerning the `closed` class?  Should every closed `h4` have it, or just the last clicked `h4`?

Comment: I'm no jQuery expert. I wasn't trying to add the class closed. Somebody else at work told me to add that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying it with your edited question, i got it to working using this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#winners-table div').hide();
        $('div#winners-table h4').click(function(){
            $('div#winners-table h4.closed').removeClass('closed');
            $('div#winners-table h4.open').each(function(){
                $(this).attr('class', 'closed').siblings('div').slideUp();
            });

            if(!$(this).hasClass('open') && !$(this).hasClass('closed')){
              $(this).addClass('open');
              $(this).siblings('div').slideDown();
            }else{
               $(this).removeClass('open');
            }

       });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work - well that's not true actually - it does mean that the `<div>` slides back up when the `<h4>` is clicked.

However, removing the line `$(this).siblings('div').slideUp();` stops the other `<div>`s from closing - only one needs to be visible at a time. Also, removing the each loops - leaves the class `open` active when clicking on the `<h4>`

Comment: It would probably be more helpful if you included your HTML markup as well. Your question implies it's a single `<div>` within the `<h4>`

Comment: I've added ion the HTML, apologies.

Comment: Something funky's going on with the way you're classes are being called. Once the 'closed' class was added, it was never being removed, and toggleClass was also active counter-intuitively, so I just went old school. Hope it works the way you expect it to.

Comment: Looks like this is the way to go (using `addClass`/`removeClass`).  `attr('class', 'closed')` seems to act like `addClass`.

Comment: Might be old school but works exactly as expected. Thanks for your help Munch.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because, after closing all `h4.open`, you still `slideToggle()` the clicked `h4`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#winners-table div').hide();
        $('div#winners-table h4').click(function(){
            var clicked = this;
            $('div#winners-table h4.open').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('class', 'closed');
                if (clicked != this) {
                    $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
                    }
                });
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle();
            });
        });
```

^  I added a check where the clicked `h4` wouldn't `slideUp()`, so the `slideToggle()` would do its job as expected.

---

**EDIT**

Here's my entire HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#winners-table div').hide();
        $('div#winners-table h4').click(function(){
            var clicked = this;
            $('div#winners-table h4.open').each(function() {
                $(this).attr('class', 'closed');
                if (clicked != this) {
                    $(this).siblings('div').slideUp();
                    }
                });
            $(this).toggleClass('open');
            $(this).siblings('div').slideToggle();
            });
        });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="winners-table">
        <h3>h3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>H4</h4>
                <div>div1</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>h4 2</h4>
                <div>div 2</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>h4 3</h4>
                <div>div 3</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
                    <li>
                <h4>h4 4</h4>
                <div>div 4</div>
            </li><!-- ENDS -->
        </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I copied your HTML and only replaced the ellipses.  Tested on Firefox 3.5, Chrome 4 (dev channel), Opera 10, IE6 (via IEs4Linux) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work - it requires the user to click twice on the `<h4>`. It also doesn't close the previous `<div>` when clicking on another `<h4>`.

Comment: Then you might have omitted something essential from your HTML.  "It works on my machine."  :p  Maybe more details on what you have on your web page?  :)

Comment: Right. Safari Mac: Requires user to click twice on the `<h4>`. It also doesn't close the previous `<div>` when clicking on another `<h4>`. FF Mac, Opera Mac, IE6 WinXP, IE7 WinXP: Doesn't remove the class 'open' off of the `<h4>`.

Comment: My code is exactly the same and it's very buggy cross browser/os